# How to make sense of analytics data?

Tags: analytics, google-analytics

Are there any good resources out there for learning how to use analytics data?

I'd like to learn how to take the data and apply it practically to my site in order to make it a better experience for my visitors and ultimately increase conversions.

Also, sometimes the significance of data is obvious (the more visits the better) but sometimes not so much, like a shorter time on site could potentially be a good thing if it means that a visitor found what they were looking for more quickly.

Comment: +1, absolutely! Analytics is clearly a tool designed with management/marketing in mind. Getting info out of it is such a struggle every time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there is a link at the bottom of every page, but maybe it's worth mentioning the "Conversion University":

http://www.google.com/support/conversionuniversity/

Answer (score 0):

**[Google Analytics in Depth: Goals and Funnels](http://sixrevisions.com/tools/google-analytics-in-depth-goals-and-funnels/)**
from `Six Revisions`

Answer (score 0):

As of 2014, the current Google educational offering appears to now be housed at: https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/

The starting course, Digital Analytics Fundamentals, is here:

https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/course01

And has the following units:

```
Unit 1 - Course overview
Unit 2 - Getting started with digital analytics
Unit 3 - Understanding and using Google Analytics data
Unit 4 - Collecting actionable data with Google Analytics
Unit 5 - Navigating Google Analytics reports
Unit 6 - Navigating Conversions reports
Final assessment
Live Event #1 - Paul Muret & Justin Cutroni (video)
Live Event #1 - Paul Muret & Justin Cutroni (transcript)
Live Event #2 - Avinash Kaushik & Justin Cutroni (video)
```

Comment: I was sceptical that something on withgoogle.com would be official, but it does appear to be linked from https://www.google.com/analytics/learn/